Textures Will Not Stop Flickering After Animation
I'm in the rendering stage for my newest project and I've noticed that after I render there are alot of textures that seem to flicker continuously throughout the animation. I've tried the following based on my google searches but nothing seems to work:

Flipped normals of object for all those are were facing the wrong way.
Selecting the objects individually and clicking "merge by distance" to get rid of any double faces. When I did this the popup message at the bottom stated "removed 0 veriticies.
Checked to make sure objects were set on auto smooth.

I provided two short examples of the some objects flickering. In the first video, if you look at the room to the left or the floor to the right, or the right plane I put in for this test, you can see that the texture seems to shimmer/flicker. I have a feeling this might relate to the lighting but I'm not sure as nothing I found on google/youtube seemed to point to this being the issue.
The second video I provided shows the same thing (this one much easier to see) on the column on the left side.
Also maybe important to mention, alot of the textures I use come from the add-on "Sanctus Library". I'm not sure if that has anything to do with it or not.
Example Footage
Example 2

Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload images or gifs, along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.
